# Using Uploadify with Sharepoint and .net

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, wss, uploadify

I have a some html being generated by JQuery on a Share Point page. I want to use uploadify in this html to upload a file to the server. [Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25427/alexander-gyoshev) has helped by providing the following sample code which is based partially  on http://www.uploadify.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=45.

upload.ashx

```
<%@ Assembly Name="ClassName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f099e668beaaa0f9" %>
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" CodeBehind="Upload.ashx.cs" Class="Site.RootFiles.TEMPLATE.LAYOUTS.other.Upload" %>
```

upload.ashx.cs

```
public class Upload : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
    HttpPostedFile oFile = context.Request.Files["Filedata"];

   if (oFile != null) {
   const string sDirectory = "c:\\";
   if (!Directory.Exists(sDirectory))
   Directory.CreateDirectory(sDirectory);

   oFile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(sDirectory, oFile.FileName));

   context.Response.Write("1");
        }
        else {
            context.Response.Write("0");
        }
    }
    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The file is not uploading to the server. The only event being thrown is the onProgress one. Navigating to _layouts/other/Upload.ashx returns 0 (this is correct) so the file is there.

The main question is how do I get this to play with share point? I try remote debugging the upload.ashx file but it won't allow me to add breakpoints in VS so remote debugging does nothing.

**Update 1**

This question [Visual Studio ASHX files debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334538/visual-studio-ashx-files-debugging) got debugging working.

When I navigate directly to the page 0 is written to the page. The debugger fires and everything is good. When the script run it's not hitting Upload.ashx as no breakpoints are hit. I imagine my reference to Upload.ashx is incorrect. I tried using http://mysite/_layouts/other/Upload.ashx in the js and still no joy...

**Update 2**

After some testing the problem seems to be that it is asking me to log into Share Point again (I am logged in). This is causing it to trip over. Any ideas how to make sure that my authenication is picked up?

**Update 3**

This is really strange. I am tempted to say it is a setting in my IE8 that is doing it as it works for a team mate.

When I browse directly to /_layouts/other/Upload.ashx it I am never asked to authenticate.
When I go via JS I am sometimes asked to authenicate even if I have logged in before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't upload to a page, but to a [http handler](http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/020417.htm). You should add the code that you pasted to a **upload.ashx**, as specified in the forum post. Then, on the client, use uploadify like this:

```
$("#fileInput1").uploadify ({ script: 'upload.ashx' });
```

Comment: getting the following error:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   at Upload.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() 
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Comment: The third post in the thread shows some drama with the folders (http://www.uploadify.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=45#p1909). Either this throws the exception, or the file does not arrive on the server - can you check which one?

Comment: I tried the second lot of code and still no luck. Not getting far with debugging. Why are things never simple.

Comment: Well, the last thing I can think of is that the destination directory does not have proper permissions set. Here's a sample website that demonstrates the approach - it should be enough to get you going: http://gyoshev.net/temp/stackoverflow/Uploadify.zip

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine, I just get nothing when I push it onto my share point site. The error function is not being thrown. Progress is thrown once.